# How to use <vector> with constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, vector

How could I use `<vector>` for an **array of objects**, which need to be given value through constructors? e.g class with name,age would need to get in an array with information given through constructor `Student(string n, int a ) { name = n , age = a }` .

All the data will be given through keyboard..

Comment: Any chance of letting us know the language

Comment: C++ . I'm sorry

Comment: Well add the tag

Comment: Your question is unclear - have another go

Comment: What's wrong with `std::vector<Student>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example code of a program capable of getting and storing the name and the age of a list of students using vectors. After that, it prints the information stored. I am using MSVC as the compiler, so if you are not on windows, you can remove `system("pause")`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student {
public:
    Student(string n, int a) : name(n), age(a) {}

    string GetName(void) { return name; }
    int GetAge(void) { return age; }

private:
    string name;
    int age;

};

int main(void) {
    vector<Student> students;

    unsigned int n;

    cout << "How many students are there?" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        string name;
        int age;

        cout << endl << "Please give me the information of the student " << i + 1 << endl;

        cout << "What is the name of the student?" << endl;
        cin >> name;

        cout << "What is the age of the student?" << endl;
        cin >> age;

        students.push_back(Student(name, age));
    }

    cout << endl << "Printing information of the students" << endl << endl;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        Student& student = students[i];

        cout << "Student " << i + 1 << " is " << student.GetName() << " and is " << student.GetAge() << " years old." << endl;
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If there is nothing else to be asked, you can accept my answer, or zett42's answer which has more ways of pushing an element into the vector.

Answer (score 0):

One can use an [initializer-list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) to directly construct a `vector` of students:

```
std::vector<Student> students{
    { "John", 22 },
    { "Melissa", 19 }
};
```

To add a student later one could use member function [`emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) which just forwards its arguments to the `Student` constructor:

```
students.emplace_back( "Andy", 23 );
```

Pre C++11 one would have to use member function [`push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) instead:

```
students.push_back( Student( "Andy", 23 ) );
```

More usage examples can be found on the linked reference pages.

Comment: Thank you , I needed a version with values given from the keyboard

Comment: @sebbyz Well, if you need someone to do the assignment for you, look for the other answer.